# used bundler and rbenv -- but still cannot find gems

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rbenv

I run `bundle install` and I get a list saying all the gems are installed.

`bundle show shotgun => /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/shotgun-0.9`

`shotgun webpost.rb =>`

```
   /Users/angela/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'shotgun' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/angela/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/angela/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/shotgun:22:in `<main>'
```

**PROBLEM: Bundler says gems are installed, but both running them or trying to require from irb shows them unfound!  How can I access my gems?**

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run commands from within the context of bundler:

```
bundle exec shotgun webpost.rb
```